# Do I need to store paths to my files or can I simply note their storage type?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-camera, android-sdcard, android-image

I did some testing and, with an Android emulator, outputted a few pathways:

Internal Storage `context.getFilesDir()` has path `/data/data/package_name/files`

Private External Storage with `context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` has path `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/packagename/files/`

Public External Storage with `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` has path `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/`

In my app, I've defined an object that has a timestamp string and an array for images (more specifically, paths to those images), and this information is stored in a sqlite database.

But is this a bad idea? Because if someone wanted to move this app to another device, wouldn't the paths change? I'm a little confused as to how files can be moved around, how different devices impact this situation, etc. I am confused as to what the correct approach is for storing image references in the sqlite table. Do you store absolute paths like above? Or do you store a number representing whether the pic is internal/private external/public external and pull that way regardless of device/file structure?

I'm just trying to make sure I don't publish an app that lacks some critical feature simply because I misunderstood something. Like if I start using an app that can take pictures/store them internally, it's all on internal storage, all on this phone. But if I want to start saving pics to an SD card or something else, I have to change where I store the pics and how I reference them. And what if I upgrade my phone? I'd have to somehow carry/transfer all that stuff to a new infrastructure, etc. Or the "cloud", even.

In other words I am just trying to understand all the possible use cases, here, in terms of how Android app data is stored and transferred.

Comment: What do you mean with  if someone wanted to move this app to another device? do you mean Install this app in other devices?

Comment: @MiguelBenitez As in, they decide to buy a new phone for whatever reason, yes. New phone, but they want all their old data from the app on the old phone to be transferred over in some way.

Comment: If you want to support this functionality I think you should create your own server to upload this images and them download from the other device. It's not related with the way that you storage those images, an app run in a sandbox and you can't copy this app to another device directly, you need to download from a market or install manually from scratch

Comment: The only thing you have to store is the file name (not a comlete path) and the location type. You mentioned internal |external|pictures. So for instance `external/mypicture.jpg`.

Comment: @greenapps So if I had a table for my picture links, since I'd be naming the files after their timestamps, I could just store the timestamp and whether the picture is internal/external public/external private, and then construct from that the appropriate filepath?

Comment: @MiguelBenitez So there's not a situation where someone would, for instance, want to save everything to an SD card, get a new phone, and then re-insert the SD card, but suddenly the new phone OS wants to look in a new location because it has a different definition of default external paths?

Comment: In this case if you use File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "YourAPPName/Photos"); to set the folder, is going to be always the same for every device. But the user have to download again the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions are a little broad. I will try to answer them in turns:

> But is this a bad idea?

Not in itself. The issue here is how are you managing changes and the Android alterations that may occur in the future (as well as the versions you are currently supporting)

> Because if someone wanted to move this app to another device, wouldn't the paths change?

Relative paths would never change. They were implemented (I am guessing around API 2~6) to ensure that hard disk management would not be necessary in apps. By getting the `Enviroment.getExternalFilesDir(stuffs..)` you would garantee a path to the same file, regardless of readl disk allocation.

> how files can be moved around, how different devices impact this situation, etc.

Files from Desktops (PC, Mac, Linux, Ubuntu, etc) follow a contracted with Android devices, that simulate the same disk system. This way, a PC can save a file (png, mp3, custom, etc) in a "root folder" that becomes the same root for `Enviroment.getExternalFilesDir(stuffs..)` BUT data private to your application is never accessible (on non-rooted devices), to the outside system.

> Do you store absolute paths like above?

You can. But I believe this goes against the system best-practices. Saving a relative path, then building a `File` object, in regards to that path is the correct approach. Do note that the `File` class in Android expects you to know a bit about the file you are refferencing.... either its extension, name regex, physical location, relational location, etc... you need to know at least one of those.

#### Finally, what I think you asked:

> Can the user replicate the same content in different devices?

For this, you must ensure that the user is "know" for instance, using the Play Store account, you can then have a repository, and have devices syncronize with that repository. Or even add a "export" function, that copies files, and imports them somewhere else.

Comment: So in theory, if I saved pictures named by timestamp, I wouldn't have to actually store any paths in the db, just their timestamps? I could just have an app setting asking the user if they want to save internal, private external, or public external, and then use the corresponding Android-given default path (using the functions from the OP) and from there construct the relative folders/filenames?

Comment: Supposing all file extensions and types are equal (say a JPEG from camera pictures) and all saved in the same folder (such as `/pictures`), then saving the timestamp (file name) is enough. When acessing that, you must then ensure that the `File` still exists (user may have used a program to alter your app, such as a rooted device file app, erasing or altering the file). However, if you are using several different folders, then at least what folder might be needed as well... when you stated `then use the corresponding Android-given default path`, then yes, if you can tell what that path is.

Comment: So let's say someone wants to change from internal storage to SD card or vice-versa. Is the best practice to first ensure enough room exists, and then move everything over (as opposed to copying) to the new storage medium?

Comment: I do this in order: `Ensure disk is present`, `Ensure disk is writtable`, `Ensure my app has Writte privileges`, `Ensure initial file disk is Read/Writtable` (since I might alter them as well) , `Do per file copying` (since sometimes the available space is an estimate, rather than actual partionated space), `if ALL files saved successfully && user requests move, instead of copy/paste`  then erase the initial files.

Comment: Sounds like a solid plan. Thanks for addressing my broad questions with so much detail.